# Copying representation symbology from one ArcSDE version to another?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, symbology, representation

We are having problems with our representations when copying from an ArcGIS 9.3 database to a 10.0. Representation symbologies with dash patterns (dots, dotted lines etc.) are reset to default settings in the version 10.0 database.

The problem is the same when you copy from a 10.x to 10.x database.

Have anyone experienced the same, and what did you do to make it go away?

Answer (score 1):

With this Question having attracted no Answers or Comments in about 18 months, if it is still causing you problems, then I think it will be best for you to contact **[Esri Support](http://support.esri.com/en/)**.

On the other hand, if you were able to resolve it by upgrading to a new version, or by any other means, then I recommend that you write that up as an Answer.

Comment: I have contacted the support, and I have still not found a solution, so an answer would still be very helpfull. The problem is the same when you copy from a 10.x to 10.x database.

Comment: @Morten If Esri Support gave you an NIM number for this problem, which I think they should have, then can you record that in your Question, please?

Comment: i actually don't know, because i asked support unit of the the local Esri supplier. I think they forwarded the question to Esri, but I actually don't know.